# Invalid hook call error occurs in Stripe + React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments

Building a payment in Stripe + React. I use the example in an official document but it's not working. The payment form works but `invalid hook call` error occurs when submitting the checkout button.

The error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call.
>    Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Elements,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
  CardElement,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { stripePromise } from "../../config/stripe";

handleStripe = async (event) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("event", event);
  const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
    type: "card",
    card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <CardElement />
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleStripe()}
        >
          <span>
            Checkout
          </span>
        </button>
    </Elements>
  )
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React hooks only work in functional components.

[Only call hooks from react functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

They don't work in class-based components.

[Only call hooks at the top level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.**
>   Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function.

Can't have `useState` and `useElements` defined in the `handleStripe` callback.

Convert/factor the logic into a small functional component.
Move hooks out into the main function body.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Elements,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
  CardElement,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { stripePromise } from "../../config/stripe";

const StripeComponent = props => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const handleStripe = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("event", event);
    const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
    });
    // do something with error or paymentMethod?
  };


  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <CardElement />
        <button onClick={handleStripe} >
          <span>
            Checkout
          </span>
        </button>
    </Elements>
  );
}
```

Comment: As soon as I export this functional component (in order to use it from my checkout page) i immediately get the error again:  Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Comment: @AugustoSamaméBarrientos Hi, it would be more helpful if you opened a new stackoverflow issue (you can reference this post/solution) with *your* code implementation and debugging details. Feel free to drop a link here and I can take a look when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error, when I was just adding any Stripe component to the return value, even though I didn't use any hooks at all. The issue was that `'npm i stripe'`, `'npm i @stripe/stripe-js'` and `'@stripe/react-stripe-js'` installed these packages, but they **weren't added to package.json dependencies**. I added them manually and it worked out. Hope this helps